# Append to the closest Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```js
$('.main_image a').each(function() {
 var main_image = $(this).clone();
 var bloc = $(this).closest('.item-content .bloc_image');
 bloc.append(main_image);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <span class=" main_image bloc_image">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </span>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="bloc_image">
      <a href="#"></a>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class=" main_image bloc_image">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </span>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="bloc_image">
      <a href="#"></a>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want for each `.item` that the link of `.main_image` clone itself and move into `.bloc_image`

I Try it in Jquery but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that `closest()` only looks at parent elements up the DOM. The `.item-content .bloc_image` is a child of a sibling. In this case you should use `closest()` to get the nearest common parent, and then `find()`. Try this:

```js
$('.main_image a').each(function() {
  var $main_image = $(this).clone();
  $(this).closest('.item').find('.item-content .bloc_image').append($main_image);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <span class=" main_image bloc_image">
    <a href="#">main_image</a>
  </span>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="bloc_image">
      <a href="#">bloc_image</a>
      <a href="#">bloc_image</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class=" main_image bloc_image">
    <a href="#">main_image</a>
  </span>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="bloc_image">
      <a href="#">bloc_image</a>
      <a href="#">bloc_image</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the [`closest('.item-content')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) then get the inner `bloc_image` using [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
$('.main_image a').each(function() {
  var main_image = $(this).clone();
  var bloc = $(this).closest('.item').find('.item-content .bloc_image').first();
console.log(bloc);
  bloc.append(main_image);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <span class=" main_image bloc_image">
    <a href="#">asd</a>
  </span>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="bloc_image">
      <a href="#">asd</a>
      <a href="#">asd</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class=" main_image bloc_image">
    <a href="#">asdasd</a>
  </span>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="bloc_image">
      <a href="#">asdasd</a>
      <a href="#">asdasdasd</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```